# WebApi secured by Azure Active Directory called from JavaScript

Tags: sharepoint, asp.net-identity, asp.net-web-api2, office365, azure-active-directory

I have the following scenario:

1.- A web api project in Azure, that I want to secure using Azure AD (I don't mind Token, cookie, whatever, as far as it meets the entire scenario)

2.- An Azure web site in asp.net MVC, also secured by Azure AD. This website has to call the web api controller with SSO (I'm using same Azure AD in the entire scenario)

3.- Some JavaScript code running in a page in SharePoint Online, also calling the web api controller in any secure way (The Office 365 tenant is also using same Azure AD). If you don't know about SharePoint, let's say I have an SPA project where I can only use Javascript and html (no server side code).

Following some of the MS Azure AD samples and some blogs from Vittorio Bertocci I'm able to get the points 1 and 2 working fine, using OWIN and Oppen ID connect. However, seems impossible to achieve point 3. As I'm inside a page in SharePoint Online, I can only use javascript, and not any server side code. I'd like to get a valid token for the current user, that is already logged in SP, and remember that SP uses same Azure AD that web api site.
Can I call the Azure AD and get a valid token, just from client code?

I'm open to any possible solution. I can do whatever in the web api project. If you are thinking in a SharePoint app with an appPart, and the appPart calls the web api from server side code, I agree that will work, but it's an option that is not allowed at the moment :(

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE 2018**:
This is now supported by SharePoint Online and the SPFx development model, and officially documented, for instance here

[Consume enterprise APIs secured with Azure AD in SharePoint Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/use-aadhttpclient-enterpriseapi)

---

Being said that the work done meanwhile by Vittorio, Kirk, and their teams, but extending that also to Andrew that has delivered great samples, is awesome; that doesn't really fully reply the original question because one of the requirements is to don't run the component as Add-in Part.

If you try to use ADAL JS (which starts its own OAuth flow) hosting that directly in a SP page, that's not going to work, or anyway you can expect a weird behavior for the user (cause of client redirects happening on the browser).

The solution proposed by Peter Karpinski is interesting, and will work matching the requirements in the original question, but requires quite some complexity and additional management/resources.

This recent article provides an alternative solution similar to Peter's one, but requiring less 'extras' and somewhat simpler, also reusing user's SP identity.
[Consuming Azure Hosted Web API from SharePoint Online using JavaScript and Office 365 identities](http://www.silver-it.com/node/182)
 and doesn't either require the use of ADAL on the client side and the implementation of custom security provider / token issuer on the server side. 
The identity (cookie) will be passed via properly handling CORS ([documentation](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/)) on both sides.

However, as you can read in my comments to that blog, this won't work normally with IE due to its security zone implementation. You'll have to be sure you have control on IE security zones on the clients, or have an alternative solution specific for IE.

Comment: Hi Massimo, really appreciate your comment. Could you detail why it won't work using adal.js? I've never tried, but I thought it was designed for this scenario.

Comment: Hi Luis, well I assume you do understand well how OAuth and adal.js work, by requiring redirects to federated login page, and back, in order to grab the access token. If you host your JS code using adal.js in your page, then some redirects will happen which can move the user out of the current page, and (probably automatically) back to original SP page, which is going to behave weird for the user. adal.js was designed for the SPA scenario, let me say, but where your code also needs to be secured with an existing strong (shared) identity provider, which is Azure AD.

Comment: Office Add-ins are a great example on where to use a SPA or JS only solution, but which is also secured with Azure AD

Comment: thanks again Massimo. I have some experience with ADAL .net, but I need to get my hands dirty on adal.js. I'm wondering if would make any difference if we register our SP site collection as an Azure AD app, and enable the Implicit Flow on the manifest.

Comment: The way you would do that is indeed to have an application registered in your AAD, because you need to have a Client ID. This application has as at least one Reply URL matching the URL of the SP page where your control is hosted. Still, in order to obtain the access token you need to involve ADAL.JS starting the authentication flow with it. This will produce a strange behavior on the client.

Comment: Thanks Massimo. I haven't test the approach from the article you mention, but if it works fine this is another valid answer. I'm checking it as a the right one, but I hope anyone who read it, also check Vittorio and Kirk answers, as are valid for Single page apps. thanks again!

Comment: Thanks Luis, I'm experimenting this scenario for real, and I'll probably have further updates on it... To be continued...

Answer (score 4):

I have similar needs. While waiting for a Microsoft sponsored solution we’re working on the following approach.

`3)` in Your solution (i.e. HTML page with JavaScript, hosted in `SharePoint Online` and running in Browser) will call Services in `1)` (i.e. Web Api Service layer in Azure).

In Our case we only want to validate that the calls made from `SharePoint Online` (via users browser, i.e. JavaScript) originate from a correct `Office 365` / `SharePoint Online` user in our tenant. 
We are opting out of using the App Model as we only want some simple HTML / JavaScript pages in our Intranet and don’t want App Webs. The Web Api server side code is kind of our “Web Part” code behind.

**Change to the solution after trying it out and having workable code:**

The auth cookies are ReadOnly and cannot be used. Instead we have registered one metod in our service layer as App in SharePoint Online (via appregnew.aspx). That methods url (e.g. https://cloudservice.customer.com/api/authentication/token) is registered as App start page in the app manifest and is deployed to a site Collection.

Now we can call our App via https://customer.sharepoint.com/sites/devassets/_layouts/15/appredirect.aspx?instance_id={GUID} i a jQuery ajax call and parse the result. AppRedirect sends the correct SPAuthToken which we use in our service endpoint (i.e. App start page) to call back to SharePoint and check context.Web.CurrentUser. User email is then stored in Table Storage with a generated Token which we send back to the caller (i.e. the jQuery ajax call to app redirect).

That token is then used in all other service layer calls in order to be sure of who is calling our service layer and in some cases perform authorization in our service layer.

Note, You can use the same approach in order to store Refresh and AccessToken in your client and provide that in all calls to your service from your client and use those tokens in order to do App Calls back to SharePoint. This enables HTML UI in SharePoint host webs and server code using user context in Azure service layer.

Comment: This is brilliant! Thanks for sharing. So, you are deploying your asp.net webapi as a SP app, setting the start page to any valid webapi call (auth/token). What I don't fully understand is what is the result of the jQuery call to the appredirect.aspx. How do you finally get the Bearer token to send to the webapi?

Answer (score 3):

To follow up, ADAL.js has recently been released, and the ability to use CORS with O365 APIs was recently added, enabling a scenario for script clients to communicate with services protected by Azure AD, such as your Web API.

http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/adal-js-cors-with-o365-apis-files-sharepoint

Comment: Many thanks Kirk! now that's the right answer to the question.

Answer (score 1):

As of today AAD does not support the OAuth2 implicit flow (or OpenId Connect variants) hence you can't obtain a token from AAD using a user-agent (browser), regardless of whether you hit the wire handcrafting the protocol or using a library.
However keep an eye on future announcements, as this is an important scenario for us!
HTH
Cheers,

### V.

**update** we now support the implicit flow on our server, and we released a library for helping you consume the new feature: http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2015/02/19/introducing-adal-js-v1/
Thank youi for r your patience!

Comment: Thanks Vittorio !!
feeling better knowing that I'm not missing anything and that MS is working on this scenario. Looking forward those future announcements. Count me in as an early adopter :)
Cheers.

Comment: FINALLY seems that we have the solution from Microsoft. haven't tested yet in a SP page, but should work: http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/10/28/adal-javascript-and-angularjs-deep-dive/

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you say you can use only HTML/JS let me guess you're having a SharePoint-hosted App.

Azure AD Authentication Library (ADAL) doesn't provide yet in this moment support for HTML5.
I've been looking since a while (almost one year) on how to implement something as you say; but I couldn't find any working solution, which doesn't make use also of some 'code-behind'.

I'd suggest you then to move to a Provider-hosted App, where you'll be able to have some C# code, and make use of ADAL to retrieve and reuse the OAuth token.
Also, I think is worth to look at this documentation page:

[Choose patterns for developing and hosting your app for SharePoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179887%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

at section [Match your hosting pattern with your development goals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179887%28v=office.15%29.aspx#MatchPattern)

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your help.

Well, it's not a SP-Hosted App, but it's same scenario. It's just a SP page in SP Online, so I can only use JS code like in a SP-hosted app.

As I said in my question, I agree the Provider hosted app is likely the right (or at least, the unique) solution, but that means to build and app, deploy it, and add teh appPart manually to the page (is not easy to package in a WSP). So, this solution is quite hard, when you only want to make some AJAX calls and show some data.

However, after all that I've seen, I think we can't do anything else. I'm gonna wait some more days to see if someone know any weird workarround that could work, and if not, I'll mark your answer as valid.

Thanks again!